# How to properly add constraints to my UITextField, which contains a UILabel using SWIFT?

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints

I'm relatively new to programming in general, and I'm only starting to pickup constraints and auto-layout and how to set things up properly. Currently, what I'm trying to figure out is how to make the top most UITextfield with the UILabel inside of it (The one that says Weight(lbs): 70.0) align to the specs that I have configured for it (See code bellow...).

When I specify the size of the width and length anchors, I always get a View that ignores my size specs and anchors to the entire screen (see image bellow).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    var stats : Results<WeightSetsReps>?

    var weightTextField = UITextField()
    var weightLabel = UILabel()

    var repsTextField = UITextField()
    var repsLabel = UILabel()

    var timerImage = UIImageView()


    var selectedExercise : Exercises? {
        didSet{
            loadWsr()
        }
    }


    //MARK: - ViewDidLoad()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        timeClock()
        navConAcc()
        labelConfig()
        setTextFieldConstraints()
//        setImageViewConstraints()
    }


    //MARK: - UILabel
    func labelConfig(){
        weightTextField.placeholder = "Total weight..."
        weightTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        weightTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        weightTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        weightTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

        weightLabel.text = "  Weight (lbs): "
        weightLabel.textColor = .black

        weightTextField.leftView = weightLabel
        weightTextField.leftViewMode = .always


        repsTextField.placeholder = "Number of Reps..."
        repsTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        repsTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        repsTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        repsTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor


        repsLabel.text = "  Repetitions: "
        repsLabel.textColor = .black

        repsTextField.leftView = repsLabel
        repsTextField.leftViewMode = .always

        [weightTextField, repsTextField].forEach{view.addSubview($0)}

    }

    //MARK: - TextField Constrainst
    func setTextFieldConstraints(){

        weightTextField.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, size: .init(width: 20, height: 20))

        repsTextField.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, size: .init(width: 20, height: 20))
    }

    //MARK: - ImageView Constraints
//    func setImageViewConstraints(){
//
//        timerImage.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 40, left: 40, bottom: 450, right: 50))
//
//    }





    //MARK: - Navigation Bar Setup
    func navConAcc(){
        navigationItem.title = selectedExercise?.exerciseName
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    //MARK: - Stopwatch
//    func timeClock(){
//        let image1 = UIImage(named: "stopwatch")
//        timerImage = UIImageView(image: image1)
//        timerImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
//        self.view.addSubview(timerImage)
//    }

    //MARK: - Load Data
    func loadWsr() {
        stats = selectedExercise?.wsr.sorted(byKeyPath: "sets", ascending: true)
    }

    //MARK: - Save Data
    func save(wsr : WeightSetsReps){
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(wsr)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error saving wsr data \(error)")
        }
    }

}

extension UIView {
    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero){

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top).isActive = true
        }

        if let leading = leading {
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left).isActive = true
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: padding.bottom).isActive = true
        }

        if let trailing = trailing {
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: padding.right).isActive = true
        }

        if size.width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
        }

        if size.height != 0 {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove bottom anchor

```
repsTextField.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom:nil, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, size: .init(width: 20, height: 20))
```